# Got an error when I build WebRTC with rtc_use_h264=true

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, libtool-xcode

Got an error when I build WebRTC.

This is my build args

```
INFO:root:Building WebRTC with args: target_os="ios" ios_enable_code_signing=false 
use_xcode_clang=true is_component_build=false is_debug=false is_component_build=false 
rtc_include_tests=false rtc_enable_protobuf=false use_rtti=true use_custom_libcxx=false 
rtc_use_h264=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" is_debug=false target_cpu="arm64" 
ios_deployment_target="10.0" rtc_libvpx_build_vp9=true enable_ios_bitcode=false 
use_goma=false enable_dsyms=true enable_stripping=true
```

Full error log:

```
INFO:root:Building target: framework_objc
ninja: Entering directory `/webrtc-checkout/src/out_ios_libs/arm64_libs'
[85/168] LIBTOOL-STATIC obj/third_party/ffmpeg/libffmpeg_internal.a
FAILED: obj/third_party/ffmpeg/libffmpeg_internal.a
rm -f obj/third_party/ffmpeg/libffmpeg_internal.a && TOOL_VERSION=1592470677 python ../../build/toolchain/mac/filter_libtool.py /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -D  -o obj/third_party/ffmpeg/libffmpeg_internal.a -filelist obj/third_party/ffmpeg/libffmpeg_internal.a.rsp
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file list file: obj/third_party/ffmpeg/libffmpeg_internal.a.rsp is empty
```